# Прочитать последнюю строку в тхт файле

Tags: java, android

Подскажите пожалуйста, нужно прочитать последнюю строку в тхт файле..
Нашел такой пример, но он не выводит юникод(вместо него кракозябры), можно этот код как-то подправить, или подскажите другое решение?

```
private static String ReadLastLine(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String result = null;
    try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r")) {
        long startIdx = file.length();
        while (startIdx >= 0 && (result == null || result.length() == 0)) {
            raf.seek(startIdx);
            if (startIdx > 0)
                raf.readLine();
            result = raf.readLine();
            startIdx--;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: пересохраните тхт-файл в UTF-8

Comment: Посмотрите здесь принятый ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964892/how-to-read-utf8-encoded-file-using-randomaccessfile

Comment: Если в конце return result; заменить на String utf8 = new String(result.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
        return utf8; то работает вроде..

Answer (score 2):

```
String current, last = null;
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/file"));
while ((current = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    last = current;
}
System.out.println(last);//result
```

Answer (score 1):

В apache commons-io есть [ReversedLinesFileReader](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/input/ReversedLinesFileReader.html).
Он читает файл снизу вверх, соответственно вам достаточно прочитать только первую строку:

```
private static String readLastLine(File file) throws IOException {
    ReversedLinesFileReader fr = new ReversedLinesFileReader(file);
    String result = fr.readLine();
    fr.close();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Правда я что-то так и не разобрался с ходу, как его подключить..